# How to manage Cisco ASA context in Active/Active failover

Tags: cisco-asa, failover

all.

I have  two Cisco ASA 5512-X in Active/Active faiover pair. And four context on them. Usually to edit configuration I go to admin context via SSH, than issue command "changeto context CONTEXTNAME", edit configuration of context, save it.

But now I want to  allocate context to different ASAs. Problem appears when I try to go from admin context to context, with active on different ASA. In this case, when I issue command "configure terminal", I will see warning about "config not replicating from standby unit to active".

So, how can i edit configuration of this kind of contexts. Do I need to open ssh on every context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to SSH into each context. Contexts were intended to be configured by different administrators.